# Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'int error

Tags: java, android

I'm setting dexter library functions in my android application code.This loop was to check for the location services, if they are on so to start the map activity.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(depressionHelpline.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            startActivity(new Intent(depressionHelpline.this,MapActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        }
```

I expect it to work normally but it shows this error

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'int' Condition 'Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED' is always 'false' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Inspection info: This inspection analyzes method control and data flow to report possible conditions that are always true or false, expressions whose value is statically proven to be constant, and situations that can lead to null ability contract violations.
>   Variables, method parameters and return values marked as `@Nullable` or `@NotNull` are treated as null able (or not-null, respectively) and used during the analysis to check null ability contracts, e.g. report `NullPointerException` (NPE) errors that might be produced.
>   More complex contracts can be defined using @Contract annotation, for example:
>   `@Contract("_, null -> null")` — method returns null if its second argument is null `@Contract("_, null -> null; _, !null -> !null")` — method returns null if its second argument is null and not-null otherwise `@Contract("true -> fail")` — a typical assert False method which throws an exception if true is passed to it 
>   The inspection can be configured to use custom @`Nullable`
>   `@NotNull` annotations (by default the ones from annotations.jar will be used)strong text

Comment: you are aware that == doesn't compare values of Objects?

Comment: then what should i do to make that compare?

Comment: string1.equals(string2)

Comment: @KaranNayyar see my the answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its just a bracket problem..
Replace your line with this line.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(depressionHelpline.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go inside **Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** then you can see the actual value is string :-

```
public static final String ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION";
```

And
**PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED** is returning an integer value:-

```
public static final int PERMISSION_GRANTED = 0;
```

**Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** this is a string and **PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED** is an integer then how can we compare String and Int.
The right way to do is :-

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//            Permission is granted. do your work here
        } else {
//            Permission is not granted. Request permission
        }
```